# For each loop into bootstrap slider

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I come from a Java background and never really have the need for foreach loops, but due to career and personal study I am getting heavily into php. I am still trying to get my head around them and am struggling to incorporate a conditional within it. I believe I may use to use a key array but I am completely lost. If you could explain how to achieve this, plus best practice.

Here you can the foreach loop I am trying to incorporate:

```
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>

    <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
    <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
    <?php } ?>

  <?php } ?>
```

Into this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>In the Spotlight</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
        <!--/well-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance to those who help

Comment: Yes. So there is 12 images which are derived from this foreach loop. 4 items are active, 8 are not. But there is 4 images on each (3) carousel slide

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough example of how you can do it. Its pretty silly but it does the job and you should be able to understand it.

```
<?php 

// echo code from the start .. until <div class="carousel-inner"> <div class="item active">

$inserted = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) { 
    if (array_key_exists('thumb', $product) && !empty($product['thumb'])) {
        ++$inserted;
        // echo '... code from each row, e.g. <div class="col-md-3" ....',

        if ($insert % 4 == 0)  { // call this for every 4 images
            // echo the end of the row
        }

        if ($insert == 12) {
            // echo the final part because we displayed 12 items now
            break; // exit the loop after the 12 items
        } else {
            // echo the start of a row again because we haven't got 12 yet
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: can you explain this little further